# How to decode / separate php encoded json in jquery.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to decode my encoded json to jquery and set all separated code to different form element. Here I post my all code.

**php code..**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['passid']) === true && empty($_POST['passid'])=== false)
{
    //$q = $_POST['increament'];[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
    mysql_select_db('kmk_inst');
    $query = mysql_query("select Q_Id, QP_Name, Question from question_paper where Q_Id = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['passid']))."'")
    or die("Wrong Query".mysql_error());
    //echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0 , 'QP_Name'): 'passid not found';
    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if ( mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0 ) {
        $data = json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-lg-2" style="float: right; margin:10px;" id="savenext" name="savenext" onclick="return dataPass()">Save & Next</a></span>
<input type="text" style="width: 410px;text-align: center; margin: 0px;" class="onlyNumber form-control pull-left" id="ques" value="1" name="ques" />
<input type="text" style="width: 410px;text-align: center; margin: 0px;" class="onlyNumber form-control pull-left" id="QPt" value="1" name="QPt" />
```

** jquery **

```
$('a#savenext').on('click',function(){
var passid = $('input#ques').val();
//var name = $('input#QPt').val();
if($.trim(passid) != '')
{
        $.post('retrivedata.php', { passid: passid}, function(data){

            //$.each(data, function(i, name) {
            //      alert(name.Q_Id);
            //});
            $('div#datatable').text(data);
            //$('input#QPt').text(QPt);
        });
    }
});
```

I am new to jquery Ajax and JavaScript so I can`t handle it. any help appreciate.

Currently I am getting result like this.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` ?

Comment: Be wary about using the `mysql` functions as they have been superceded by `mysqli` and `PDO`. Also your code is *wide* open to SQL injection

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking for. Please specify.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(data)` or `$.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: How can I store / set it in different form element.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the proper header in the php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

jquery will take care of the parsing

to add the data to your page use append

```
      $('body').append('<form><p>'+data.Question+'<input value="'+data.QP_Name+'"></from>');
```

```js
var data = {
  "Q_Id": "1",
  "QP_Name": "test1",
  "Question": "Which is indian capital.?"
};
$('#ques').val(data.Question);
$('#QPt').val(data.QP_Name);
$('body').append('<form><p>' + data.Question + '<input value="' + data.QP_Name + '"></from>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-lg-2" style="float: right; margin:10px;" id="savenext" name="savenext" onclick="return dataPass()">Save & Next</a></span>
<input type="text" style="width: 410px;text-align: center; margin: 0px;" class="onlyNumber form-control pull-left" id="ques" value="1" name="ques" />
<input type="text" style="width: 410px;text-align: center; margin: 0px;" class="onlyNumber form-control pull-left" id="QPt" value="1" name="QPt" />
```

Comment: I already try this but not working.. any other solution.. please

Comment: what do you mean by not working?can you provide a json data sample?

Comment: {"Q_Id":"1","QP_Name":"test1","Question":"Which is indian capital.?"}
This is my current output. without your code.

Comment: then you don't need a loop

Comment: When I use your code it show me some text like "unspecified field".

Comment: I don't know why, but I test your code and it display only undefined with input field.

Comment: are you sure that you have that output?,can you post a screenshot of your  xhr request?

Comment: yes I got same output as I post here in comment. I got this output before your code and one more thing I am importing this ".js" to my html page

How can I set this answer "data.QP_Name" in above "('div#datatable')".

Comment: when you console.log(data) what do you get?

Comment: see my updated fiddle if you want to alter only the values of the input fields

Answer (score 0):

Set json as being the data type of your ajax call return like so:

```
$('a#savenext').on('click',function(){
var passid = $('input#ques').val();
//var name = $('input#QPt').val();
if($.trim(passid) != '')
{
        $.post('retrivedata.php', { passid: passid}, function(data){

            //$.each(data, function(i, name) {
            //      alert(name.Q_Id);
            //});
            $('div#datatable').text(data);
            //$('input#QPt').text(QPt);
        },'json');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am already retrieving json array but I can't able to separate them.?

Comment: what do you mean by 'separate'?

Comment: I want to store all columns to different different html field and Now I got it.

Comment: please correct your code and let others know what you did in order to get it to work. if any of the answer given was the correct one please mark it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#savenext').on('click',function(){
  var passid = $('input#ques').val();

if($.trim(passid) !=)
{
    $.post('retrivedata.php', {passid: passid}, function(data){          

        var da = JSON.parse(data);              
        $('div#datatable').text(da.QP_Name);            
        //alert(da.QP_Name);             
    });

  }
});
```