# How to set json array to html form div.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Here is my first question [How to decode / separate php encoded json in jquery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410352/how-to-decode-separate-php-encoded-json-in-jquery/42410696?noredirect=1#comment71976913_42410696)

I am working with same this question code, I can get and set my retrieved array
separately but I can't not set it in HTML format. Here I put my code with HTML.This code work with page load. `window.onload function(){};`.
any help appreciate.

```
var j=0;
var k=0;
if($.trim(passid) != 0)
{
    $.post('retrivedata.php', { passid: passid}, function(data){             
        alert(1);       
        var da = JSON.parse(data);              
        alert(22);
        //alert(text(da.QP_Name));
        $('div#datatable').text(da.QP_Name);
        $('div#datatable1').text(da.Question);

                strtable += '';
                strtable += '<div class="col-lg-12" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left:50px; padding-top: 25px">';
                strtable += '<span>';                   
                $.each(da, function(i, field)){
                    if(k % 6 === 0){
                        strtable +=
                        strtable += '<div class="col-lg-2" id="'+Que+i+'">';
                        strtable += '<figure class="wp-caption"><div class="col-lg-2"><img class="demo" src="assets/images/ico1.png" alt="2" />';
                        strtable += '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">'+j+'</figcaption></div></figure>';
                        strtable += '<div>' + da[i]['Q_Id'] + '</div>';
                        strtable += '</div>';
                    }else{
                        strtable += '<div class="col-lg-2" id="'+Que+i+'">';
                        strtable += '<figure class="wp-caption"><div class="col-lg-2"><img class="demo" src="assets/images/ico1.png" alt="2" />';
                        strtable += '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">'+j+'</figcaption></div></figure>';
                        strtable += '<div>' + da[i]['Q_Id'] + '</div>';
                        strtable += '</div>';
                    }
                    k++; j++;
                }
                strtable += '</span>';
                strtable += '</div>';

                $('div#EnglishLangImageBox').html(strtable);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you able to display any data.your code does not look right.

Comment: without loop code this work well. but when I try to add json to html it didn'twork.? How can i do this. I want to do this with element grid of 5 item each.

Comment: at least include your initial html.

Comment: why didn't you accept any answer to the question you have referred. once your problem is solved you should close the question by marking the best answer selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping is wrong change your code to something like this:

**NOTE:** This example usages a sample data which may not match to yours.

```js
  var da=[];
 for(var i=0;i <10;i++){
  da[i]=[];
  da[i]['Q_Id']='Q_Id'+i; 
 }
 var strtable="",k=0,j=0,Que="Text";
 strtable += '<div class="col-lg-12" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left:50px; padding-top: 25px">';
 strtable += '<span>';    
 $.each(da, function(i, field){
     if(k % 6 === 0){
      strtable +="</span>";//close the opened span
      strtable +="</div>";//close the opened div
      strtable += '<div class="col-lg-12" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left:50px; padding-top: 25px">';//open new div
      strtable += '<span>';   //open new span
         strtable += '<div class="col-lg-2" id="'+Que+i+'">';
         strtable += '<figure class="wp-caption"><div class="col-lg-2"><img class="demo" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/office/PNG/512/Computer_Hardware/mouse_left_click-512.png" alt="2" style="width:32px;height:32px;"/>';
         strtable += '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">'+j+'</figcaption></div></figure>';
         strtable += '<div>' + da[i]['Q_Id'] + '</div>';
         strtable += '</div>';
     }else{
         strtable += '<div class="col-lg-2" id="'+Que+i+'">';
         strtable += '<figure class="wp-caption"><div class="col-lg-2"><img class="demo" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/office/PNG/512/Computer_Hardware/mouse_left_click-512.png" alt="2" style="width:32px;height:32px;" />';
         strtable += '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">'+j+'</figcaption></div></figure>';
         strtable += '<div>' + da[i]['Q_Id'] + '</div>';
         strtable += '</div>';
     }
     k++; j++;
 });
 strtable += '</span>';
 strtable += '</div>';

 $('#EnglishLangImageBox').html(strtable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EnglishLangImageBox">

 
 </div>
```